# Add Subtotal of Each Group into Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, sum

I'm having a bit of trouble writing up a code concisely (I already have a working code but ideally I want to shorten it down as much as possible since it's huge and messy)

I have a dataframe which looks like this

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 4 |
| Total A |  |
| B | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| Total B |  |
| C | 6 |
| Total C |  |
| D | NaN |
| Total D |  |

Is there a concise way to just sum up and fill in the `Total...` rows for each group such that I get a dataframe like this?

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 4 |
| Total A | 6 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| Total B | 9 |
| C | 6 |
| Total C | 6 |
| D | NaN |
| Total D | NaN |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby function with mean function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', 2), ('A',4), ('B', 5), ('B', 3)], columns=['Group', 'Value'])
df_sum = df.groupby(by='Group').mean()
print(df_sum)
```

or alternatively, if you want totals in same df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', 2), ('A',4), ('B', 5), ('B', 3)], columns=['Group', 'Value'])

df.loc[4] = ('Total A', df[df['Group']=='A'].mean()['Value'])
df.loc[5] = ('Total B', df[df['Group']=='B'].mean()['Value'])
print(df)
```

Ordering data as you wish could be a bit tricky though as there is no easy way to sort the order you want or even insert at a row location but it could be fudged with another index column containing the order you want. Maybe rename totals as 'A Total' and 'B Total' then use sort_index()